How to create generic map in Automapper with complex mapping for member
Let's say I have ResponseModels<T> and ResponseDTOs<T> both with properties IEnumerable<T> and int TotalCount
I know I can create generic mapping using
CreateMap(typeof(ResponseModels<>), typeof(ResponseDTOs<>));

My goal is to take only MaxOutListLength of items during mapping. I know I can create complex mapping for member using the following (but only if generic type is defined).
CreateMap<ResponseModels<Order>, ResponseDTOs<OrderDTO>>()
    .ForMember(
        dst => dst.Items,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(
            src =>
            src.Items!.Take(MaxOutListLength))
        )
    .ForMember(
        dst => dst.Count,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(
            src =>
            src.Items.Count() > MaxOutListLength ? MaxOutListLength : src.Items.Count())
        );

How can I combine these two approaches?
I tried the following code, but object does not contain a definition for 'Items'
CreateMap(typeof(ResponseModels<>), typeof(ResponseDTOs<>))
    .ForMember(
        dst => dst.Items,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(
            src =>
            src.Items!.Take(MaxOutListLength))
        )
    .ForMember(
        dst => dst.Count,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(
            src =>
            src.Items.Count() > MaxOutListLength ? MaxOutListLength : src.Items.Count())
        );


Maybe it will sounds silly, but what is your MaxOutListLength, and where it comes from? Would be easier is you can post 2 examples of models side by side. Will be also helpful if you can add examples of your data models that you are trying to map.

You're trying to do a bad thing, or at least in a wrong way.
AutoMapper should be used to map one type into another, it shouldn't be used to do complex logic, calculations or altering mapped things.
Proper solution is to make the Items collection limited to MaxOutListLength before calling AutoMapper.
Mappings without additional configuration are the best, having custom mappings defined for many properties somehow defies the purpose of using AutoMapper.

You need to used the string based ForMember or you can define a non-generic base class/interface and Include that in the generic mapping.
